# How to pass specific annotation in Maven plugin configuration as parameter?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I want to create maven plugin that works on generate-sources phase and can be configured from outside. Something like this:

Parameter in plugin code is Annotation

```
@Parameter
private Annotation annotation;
```

And I want to set it in plugin configuration from "client" module, like:

```
<configuration>
    <annotation>com.whatever.MyAnnotation</annotation>
<configuration>
```

Is it possible to do something like that?

Comment: Basically, you want to create a Maven plugin. Refer to https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html. This question is too-broad.

Comment: @Tunaki yes, I know that I want to create Maven plugin, I stated it in the very first sentence. I want to know is there ways to pass specific annotation into configuration.

Comment: I would map the parameter as string then use some reflection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use class as parameter in this case the only way to do it is to put this class in plugin and then put it into client-code dependency, or create common maven artifact to hold those annotations and put it into both user's module and maven plugin module dependencies list. In this case they will be recognized as same class.